# Let $R=K[x,y,z]/(x^2-yz)$, where $K$ is a field. Show that $R$ is an integral domain, but not a unique factorization domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Let $R=K[x,y,z]/(x^2-yz)$, where $K$ is a field. Show that $R$ is an integral domain, but not a unique factorization domain.

My idea: Since $K$ is a field, and I want to show $R$ is an integral domain.

For this it is sufficient to show that the ideal $I=(x^2-yz)$, is a prime ideal. For this I need to show the polynomial $(x^2-yz)$ is irreducible in $K[x,y,z]$.

Can anyone suggest me how I move for irreducibility here.

My attempt for irreducibility is:

suppose that the polynomial is reducible, then $x^2-yz=(x+a)(x+b)=x^2+(a+b)x+ab$.

This implies, $a+b=0$ and $ab=yz$. I didn't find any value of $a$ and $b$, which satisfies both the equations.

Can anyone suggest me some hint for irreducibility in multivariable polynomial.

Comment: You've pretty much got it.  $a+b=0 \Rightarrow a = -b \Rightarrow a^2=yz$, but examining the $y$-degree of each side of this equation tells you it has no solution.  You also should check to confirm that there's no factorization of the form $(x^2+p_1(y, z)x+p_2(y, z))p_3(y, z)$ (where each $p_i$ is a polynomial in $y$ and $z$).